# How do I remove js from a specified page?

Tags: javascript

How do I remove js from a specified page?﻿

templates.php
[image]

Comment: Please post code as a code block, not as an image. And using drupal_add_js should be the last way, least preferable. They should be `#attached` to renderable array - then you can operate on them easily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`hook_js_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7)

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ($some_condition) {
    unset($javascript['path/to/script.js']);
  }
}
```

Comment: function newyasi_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if (current_path() == 'node/89') {
    unset($javascript['sites/all/themes/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js']);
  }
}

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare newyasi_js_alter() (previously declared in D:\WWW\newyasi\sites\all\themes\newyasi\template.php:136) in D:\WWW\newyasi\sites\all\themes\newyasi\template.php on line 289

Comment: You have the same function at line 136 and line 289 of the template.php file. You have to remove one of them.